# How to use playoutDelayHint and jitterBufferDelayHint in a Native WebRtc Java project

Tags: java, android, webrtc, webrtc-android

I'm currently using a self compiled WebRtc lib for my Android project and I try to get lowest latency for game streaming/ cloud gaming. I found out that on browsers you can use playoutDelayHint and or jitterBufferDelayHint to fine tune latency and how the underlying peer connection will handle things.

https://discourse.wicg.io/t/hint-attribute-in-webrtc-to-influence-underlying-audio-video-buffering/4038

Unfortunately I have no idea of how to use these functionality within a native WebRtc project (no browser)?

Is there a way to access and modify these flags in a native project and if not what actually must be adjusted in the WebRtc lib to achieve the same result? As I compile the WebRtc lib by my own I could just add this functionality by my own, I just don't have any idea what the playoutDelayHint and jitterBufferDelayHint flag is modifying in the background?

I found this in the native code which could be the correct part for the playbackDelayHint but not sure

https://github.com/maitrungduc1410/webrtc/blob/c2b1bad4c87a43d7e1af85e809d5abe04baf3104/api/video/video_timing.h#L116